# Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable is behaving strangely

Tags: c#, .net, environment-variables

In my console application I tried to read the application environment whether the application is running in local machine or RDP or in Citrix environment...what I found was strange!!!

When I ran the application directly from the VS 2010 **Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable** always returned "**null**" But when I ran the "**Application.exe**" from the **bin/release** folder it worked fine and I got the values as Console/RDP/Citrix.

Any ideas why running via VS its not loading the variable.

I was trying the read "**SessionName**".

Comment: I can think of two possibilities. Visual Studio provides a "Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt", which you can run from the Start menu, it's under Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - Visual Studio Tools. It looks like an ordinary command prompt, but there are additional environment variables, and maybe some removed too. Use the "Set" command to view them. This is also the environment Visual Studio itself is running under, and your program too when you run it under Visual Studio.

Comment: The other possibility has to do with the fact that when Visual Studio runs your program it runs it via a little program called YourApplicationName.vshost.exe. Maybe this interferes with how you query the environment.

Comment: Thanks RenniePet. Reg Edit answered the question.

Comment: How did you get if you are in a Citrix session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have UAC enabled, and run a program as Administrator so that you are prompted for elevated privileges, you may see this effect (no SESSIONNAME environment variable).

You can see this by comparing the output from the following command at two command prompts, one normal and one "run as Administrator":

```
SET S
```

This shows all the environment variables beginning S, so you can easily see that SESSIONNAME is missing in the "run as Administrator" command prompt.

So I think you have run Visual Studio as Administrator from a UAC-enabled account. Visual Studio then receives this altered set of environment variables, so SESSIONNAME will be null as you found. Then, when you ran the exe independently of Visual Studio, you didn't say "run as Administrator", so the SESSIONNAME variable was present.

Comment: Totally brilliant, Reg Edit. I was running the VS with admin rights....without admin rights it works fine. Thanks.